# C++ and Recursion: IntegerToString function

Tags: c++, recursion

I was trying the Open Courseware CS106b assignment 1. I am getting stuck on problem 4 which requires the use of recursion to write an integer to string convertor. We are not allowed to use any library functions that perform integer conversions.

The problem is that after every 'recursion level' the code does not keep track of the previous string, thus I am not able to append and build-onto the string.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include "console.h"
 #include "simpio.h"
 using namespace std;

/* Function prototypes */

string intToString(int n);
int stringToInt(string str);

/* Main program */

int main() {
    // [TODO: fill in the code]
    int n = getInteger("Enter number for conversion to String: ");
    cout<< "Converted to String: "<<intToString(n);
    return 0;
}

//Functions

string intToString(int n){
    double toBeDecomposed = n;
    string convertedToString;
    char ch;
    string tempString;

    if((double)(toBeDecomposed/10) >= 0.1){

        int lastDigit = (int)toBeDecomposed%10;

        toBeDecomposed = (int)(toBeDecomposed/10);

        intToString(toBeDecomposed);

        if (lastDigit == 0) {
            ch = '0';
        }
        else if (lastDigit == 1) {
            ch = '1';
        }
        else if (lastDigit == 2) {
            ch = '2';
        }
        else if (lastDigit == 3) {
            ch = '3';
        }
        else if (lastDigit == 4) {
            ch = '4';
        }
        else if (lastDigit == 5) {
            ch = '5';
        }
        else if (lastDigit == 6) {
            ch = '6';
        }
        else if (lastDigit == 7) {
            ch = '7';
        }
        else if (lastDigit == 8) {
            ch = '8';
        }
        else if (lastDigit == 9) {
            ch = '9';
        }

        tempString = string() + ch;

        convertedToString = convertedToString.append(tempString);

        cout<<convertedToString<<endl;

    }
    cout<<"Returning: "<<convertedToString<<endl;

    return convertedToString;
}

int stringToInt(string str){
    return 0; 
}
```

My debugging output shows that it only returns the last digit:

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to successfully append to the string `ConvertedToString` so that I return the whole converted integer?

Comment: While your question is already answered I have one suggestion for improvement. Loose the use of floatingpoint (double type). It is not needed, could cause rounding issues and is less efficient especially on platforms without a floatingpoint unit. Also it looks to me like your function wont work for values <= 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't doing anything with the result of your recursive function call.

The hint is that `intToString` *returns* a `string`. You're ignoring that return value when you call `intToString(toBeDecomposed);`.

Capture that return value and do something with it.

Comment: doh! thanks a lot its working now! all i had to do was add the assignment: convertedToString = intToString(toBeDecomposed);

Comment: In general though, would you say my code is written well, or can it be improved somewhere? I am trying to improve the quality of my code and I'm not sure if my code comes off as "amateur-ish"

Comment: @rrazd: It's open to quite a bit of improvement, at least IMO. I'd start by converting the individual digit with something like `char digit = input % 10 + '0';` instead of the long `if`/`then`/`else`.

Comment: ditto to @JerryCoffin suggestion; also get rid of `tempString`: note that you can use [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/) on a `string` to append a character to the end.

Answer (score 1):

your convertedToString variable is a local varible, so every time intToString function call it create new one and when recursion end and return it gets the last  convertedToString which contains the last digit.

simple solution is to make it static or global.